# is there a way to test airflow connection from CLI or by a custom dag

Tags: python, airflow

We are using airflow 2.1 version and we have multiple connections(Linux/Non Linux based OS) defined in Airflow.

We created a dag by exporting all the values from connection metadata table and running a dummy bash command

```
session = airflow.settings.Session()

t1 = session.query(Connection)
```

But because of different OS we are facing some errors. Is there any generic way through CLI or any other way we can create a dag and then test all the connections and if it fails we want to get notified .

Answer (score 1):

Airflow has the ability to test connection assuming the hook implemented `test_connection` function (see [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#test-connections)). You can test the connection from the UI in Admin -> Connections -> Choose the specific connection:

[image]

Or by using python code :

```
hook = YourHook(conn_id='your_conn_id')
status, msg = hook.test_connection()
assert status is True
assert msg == 'Connection successfully tested'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Elad. Hook means is that SSHHook ?

Comment: How can i keep this code as a generic in dag ?

Comment: @Ravi currently SSHHook doesn't have test_connection function so this won't work for it. You can create a custom hook and add this function or better yet submit such function to the Hook in the open source

Comment: Can you help me with any suggestion how can i create a custom hook and add them in dag in order to test the connection on daily basis.